# Why isn't there any std::stoui?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

Since c++11 the [`<string>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/string) header provides :

- [std::stoi](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)
- [std::stol](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)
- [std::stoll](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)

To convert from `std::string` to signed integers.

We also have their unsigned counterpart :

- [std::stoul](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stoul)
- [std::stoull](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stoul)

Now, even a child would notice something is missing right ? :)

So the question is: is there a reason not to provide an `std::stoui` or is it just something that was forgotten (And basically how could something this "obvious" be forgotten)?

Also, does that mean that the correct way of converting an `std::string` to `unsigned int` is :

```
unsigned int ui = static_cast<unsigned int>(std::stoul(std::string{"42"}));
```

Comment: Although none of *those* answers seem particularly satisfying to a sense of symmetry...

Comment: "how could something this "obvious" be forgotten" -- if it was an oversight (and I'm not saying it was) that would be surprising but not unprecedented. `copy_if` was missing from C++03. I've heard it said that was more or less due to a copy-paste error.

Comment: @BrettHale The main part of the question might be a duplicate of the first one, but i'm also realy intersted in "what is the best way to do the conversion" which is the second part of the question, or should i open another question for that ?

Comment: The answer to the second part of the question is "no", because it doesn't do a range check :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop so how to ? :)

Comment: @Drax There is a good way to do the conversion shown in Mike Seymour's answer to the other question.

Comment: `unsigned int stoui(const string &str, size_t *idx = 0, int base = 10) { unsigned long u = stoul(str, idx, base); if (u > UINT_MAX) throw out_of_range(str); return u; }`

Comment: @SteveJessop Why does it work without a cast ?

Comment: @Drax `unsigned long` is implicitly convertible to `unsigned int`.

Comment: @Simple Since when ? O_o  Can you point to some source for this plz, even an SO question ?

Comment: @Drax http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast :)

Comment: @Drax: since always. You might have to add the cast to silence a compiler warning for an implicit narrowing conversion. That depends on your compiler and options, but narrowing clearly is "safe" because of the range check.